# Spree PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm using Spree on my Ruby on Rails app, and I'm having the following error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Spree::Admin::ProductsController#create

PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (12, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 1, 2018-05-15 08:58:58.830082, 2018-05-15 08:58:58.830082, t, null, null). : INSERT INTO "spree_products" ("name", "shipping_category_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"

 log(sql, name, type_casted_binds, stmt_key) do
        @connection.exec_prepared(stmt_key, type_casted_binds.map { |_, val| val })
      end
    rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => e
      pgerror = e.original_exception
```

Now I'm not sure what is causing this problem or how to solve it.

I'm assuming it's got to do with the `spree_globalize` gem. 
I've tried to uninstall the gem but then I get the error backend missing `spree_globalize`

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

**This is the log file:**

```
Started POST "/store/admin/products" for 213.127.86.174 at 2018-05-15 08:58:58 +0000

Cannot render console from 213.127.86.174! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255

Processing by Spree::Admin::ProductsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"v==", "product"=>{"name"=>"Volks", "sku"=>"", "prototype_id"=>"", "price"=>"29", "available_on"=>"", "shipping_category_id"=>"1"}, "button"=>""}
  Spree::Preference Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "spree_preferences".* FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE "spree_preferences"."key" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["key", "spree/backend_configuration/locale"]]
  Spree::User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "spree_users".* FROM "spree_users" WHERE "spree_users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "spree_users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "spree_users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Spree::Role Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "spree_roles".* FROM "spree_roles" INNER JOIN "spree_role_users" ON "spree_roles"."id" = "spree_role_users"."role_id" WHERE "spree_role_users"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN

  Spree::Product Exists (2.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "spree_products" INNER JOIN "friendly_id_slugs" ON "friendly_id_slugs"."sluggable_id" = "spree_products"."id" AND "friendly_id_slugs"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "friendly_id_slugs"."sluggable_type" = $1 WHERE ("spree_products"."id" IS NOT NULL) AND "spree_products"."slug" = 'volks' LIMIT 1  [["sluggable_type", "Spree::Product"]]

Spree::Product Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "spree_products" INNER JOIN "friendly_id_slugs" ON "friendly_id_slugs"."sluggable_id" = "spree_products"."id" AND "friendly_id_slugs"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "friendly_id_slugs"."sluggable_type" = $1 WHERE ("spree_products"."id" IS NOT NULL) AND "spree_products"."slug" = 'volks' LIMIT 1  [["sluggable_type", "Spree::Product"]]

Spree::ShippingCategory Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "spree_shipping_categories".* FROM "spree_shipping_categories" WHERE "spree_shipping_categories"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]

Spree::Product::Translation Load (1.7ms)  SELECT DISTINCT locale FROM "spree_product_translations"  ORDER BY "spree_product_translations"."locale" ASC

Spree::Product Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT 1 AS one FROM "spree_products" INNER JOIN "spree_product_translations" ON "spree_product_translations"."spree_product_id" = "spree_products"."id" WHERE 1=0 AND ("spree_product_translations"."slug" = 'volks-f405f8ca-e79d-4bbb-ba8a-63f80a13318a' AND "spree_product_translations"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "spree_product_translations"."locale" = 'en') LIMIT 1
              SQL (1.7ms)  INSERT INTO "spree_products" ("name", "shipping_category_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [[nil, nil], ["shipping_category_id", 1], ["created_at", "2018-05-15 08:58:58.830082"], ["updated_at", "2018-05-15 08:58:58.830082"]]
               (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
            Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 49ms (ActiveRecord: 9.7ms)
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'pg', '< 1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'rake'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'kramdown'
gem 'thor', '0.19.1'
gem 'spree_braintree_vzero', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_braintree_vzero'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'capistrano-passenger'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'

end

group :development do

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

gem 'spree', '~> 3.1.0.rc1'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.1.0.rc1'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.1.0.rc1'
gem 'devise'
gem 'materialize-sass'
gem 'active_link_to'
gem 'mollie-api-ruby', '< 3.2'
# gem 'spree_mollie', github: 'salman15/mollie_spree_2017', branch: 'stable'
gem 'spree_mollie', github: 'ttcremers/spree_mollie', branch: 'stable'
gem 'spree_mail_settings', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_mail_settings'
gem 'spree_i18n', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_i18n'
gem 'spree_globalize', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_globalize', branch: 'master'
gem "mini_magick"
# gem 'rails-i18n', github: 'svenfuchs/rails-i18n', branch: 'rails-4-x' # For 4.x
# gem 'globalize', '~> 5.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `spree_globalize` from my `Gemfile.lock` file and then removed `spree_globalize` Error stopped occurring.